# Cannot restart docker in CentOS7 in k8s

Tags: docker

After executing `systemctl start docker`, I got:
Failed to start docker.service: Unit not found.
And this is the output for `systemctl status docker -l`:

```
docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2018-09-22 08:58:24 CST; 6s ago
     Docs: http://docs.docker.com
  Process: 22573 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd-current --add-runtime docker-runc=/usr/libexec/docker/docker-runc-current --default-runtime=docker-runc --exec-opt native.cgroupdriver=systemd --userland-proxy-path=/usr/libexec/docker/docker-proxy-current --init-path=/usr/libexec/docker/docker-init-current --seccomp-profile=/etc/docker/seccomp.json $OPTIONS $DOCKER_STORAGE_OPTIONS $DOCKER_NETWORK_OPTIONS $ADD_REGISTRY $BLOCK_REGISTRY $INSECURE_REGISTRY $REGISTRIES (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 22573 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Sep 22 08:58:24 VM_0_3_centos systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
Sep 22 08:58:24 VM_0_3_centos dockerd-current[22573]: Error starting daemon: pid file found, ensure docker is not running or delete /var/run/docker.pid
Sep 22 08:58:24 VM_0_3_centos systemd[1]: docker.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 22 08:58:24 VM_0_3_centos systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Sep 22 08:58:24 VM_0_3_centos systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
Sep 22 08:58:24 VM_0_3_centos systemd[1]: docker.service failed.
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the Docker PID file is still present. Try removing it:

```
rm -f /var/run/docker.pid
```

Then start the service

```
systemctl start docker
```

Answer (score 0):

If you observe the output log

```
Sep 22 08:58:24 VM_0_3_centos dockerd-current[22573]: Error starting daemon: pid file found, ensure docker is not running or delete /var/run/docker.pid
```

so please remove `docker.pid` file and try again.

```
rm /var/run/docker.pid
```